# Laravel edit route for basic CRUD application giving 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to set up a basic Laravel 9 CRUD application, and I cannot get the edit route working for the User Controller.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('dashboard'); })
    ->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('user','index')->middleware('auth')->name('cases');
    Route::get('user/create','create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/create','store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{$id}/edit','edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/{$id}/edit','update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{$id}/delete','destroy')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    function edit(int $id)
    {
        echo 123;
    }
```

I'm getting a 404 NOT FOUND page

[image]

Also, why don't I see the stack trace for this error?

Also, in some examples, I've seen people using the model class name as the parameter type in the controller method declaration, such as:

```
function edit(User $id)
{
    echo 123;
}
```

However, I've also seen other examples using **int** instead. So which is the correct one?

Comment: About the last part: if the route is user/{user} and argument is (User $user), Laravel will use dependency injection and find user based on the given identifier, in your case "id". Of course using $id instead of $user is ok, but semantically meaningless because in this case $id will be the user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, inside your .env filte you should put

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

and change your web.php to:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('dashboard'); })->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('user','index')->middleware('auth')->name('cases');
    Route::get('user/create','create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/create','store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}/edit','edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/{id}/edit','update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}/delete','destroy')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Then, try to run

```
php artisan route:list
```

and check if your routes are correct.

And try to remove middlewares inside user files, maybe you do not have login page and it redirects you there.

Be sure you are in the correct url like `localhost/user/1/edit`

Answer (score 2):

Parameters in routes don't take a starting `$`. Change all occurrences of `{$id}` in your routes to just `{id}`:

```
Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('user','index')->middleware('auth')->name('cases');
    Route::get('user/create','create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/create','store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}/edit','edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('user/{id}/edit','update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}/delete','destroy')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('user/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
});
```

More on [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters)

Edit: you might also want to take a look at [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers). Something like `Route::resource('users', UserController::class);` will manage all of the required routes

Comment: That should the roight answer!